# Drop down menu with value from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys

I have products belonging to collections. A collection is just a name. Products have a collection_id.

In my _form view that is used for creation and edition of products, i'd like to have a drop down menu with the name of all collection.

Problem, it seems there is no select method affiliated to form.for and i am trying to use :

> select(method, choices, options = {},
>   html_options = {})

from the doc but i do not understand it. I must write a methode to create a form? What are the choices, and the 2 options? Two parameters should be enough to populate an < option>
 tag.

How can I have a drop down menu alowing me to assign a collection through collection name to my product?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a collection select, first make sure your models are properly setup:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection
  has_many :products
end
```

Then add the collection select to your view:

```
<%= collection_select(:product, :collection_id, Collection.all, :id, :name) %>
```

You can also read up on the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

Comment: Thanks, my models already had belongs_to and has_many.It works fine, however, i do not understand the second parameters, the doc says it should be a method, but it is a value.

Comment: The doc means the name of the method, not the actual method. So, populate collection id on product, using the id of the selected collection and the text value of the option should be the name of each collection.

Comment: Just an additional note here, the actual method name is "collection_select" regardless of the model name, those two pieces are not related, despite how it may appear here.