# How to populate a dropdown [rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that lets users upload and comment on songs. However, I'd like to add a genres category. When users upload songs they'll be able to choose the genre of the song. This will help with when I add search.

For quick overview of the code see: www.github.com/apane/leap

I'm guessing I'd add a genres table to the db and associate it with songs e.g:

Genre belongs_to song, a song has_many genres.

But after that I'm stumped. How do I populate the genres dropdown?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?  a quick search shows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019889/drop-down-menu-with-value-from-another-model

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34557/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17979114-how-to-populate-a-dropdown-rails4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rails g model genre name
rails g model genre_song genre:belongs_to song:belongs_to
rake db:migrate
```

**models/genre.rb**

```
has_many :genre_songs
has_many :songs, through: :genre_song
```

**models/song.rb**

```
has_many :genre_songs
has_many :genres, through: :genre_song

def self.tagged_with(name)
  Genre.find_by_name!(name).songs
end

def tag_list
  genres.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(names)
  self.genres = names.split(",").map do |n|
    Genre.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end
```

**songs/index.html.erb**

```
Genres: <%= raw song.genres.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, genre_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

**songs/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Genres (separated by commas)" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>
```

**songs_controller.rb**

add `tag_list` to permited params

Answer (score 0):

After adding the genres table to your db, you can do something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:song, :genre_id, Genre.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Where :song refers to your form for uploading songs.