# How do I set/limit the input in a rails form to match another models table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to programming and haven't been able to find any resources to help me with this. I have created two scaffolds **Accounts** and **Cashbooks**. I want users to be able to add an account (with a parameter of account_name) which will then be set as the parameters for the Cashbook account input. Ideally when adding a Cashbook transaction, I would want users to see a dropdown which will contain all the account_names of the Accounts which have been created.

**Cashbook Model**

```
class Cashbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account, foreign_key: :account_name
end
```

**Cashbook Controller**

```
def new
   @cashbook = Cashbook.new
   @cashbook.account(account_params[:account_name])
  end

  def create
    @cashbook = Cashbook.new(cashbook_params)
      @cashbook.account(account_params[:account_name])

def cashbook_params
      params.require(:cashbook).permit(:date, :description, :account, :kind, :amount, :balance, :name)
      params.require(:account).permit(:account_name)
    end
```

**Cashbook DB**

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :account_name
      t.boolean :operating_expense
      t.boolean :cost_of_sales
      t.boolean :sales
      t.boolean :other_income
      t.boolean :non_current_liability
      t.boolean :non_current_asset
      t.boolean :current_asset
      t.boolean :current_liability
      t.boolean :equity
      t.integer :account_number

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Account Model**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cashbook, foreign_key: :account_name
end
```

**Account Controller**

```
def new
    @account = Account.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
  end

def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:account_name, :operating_expense, :cost_of_sales, :sales, :other_income, :non_current_liability, :non_current_asset, :current_asset, :current_liability, :equity, :account_number)
    end
```

**Cashbook db**

```
class CreateCashbooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cashbooks do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :description
      t.boolean :account
      t.string :kind
      t.integer :amount

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019889/drop-down-menu-with-value-from-another-model

Comment: why are your tables connected via account names and not ids?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) form helper.

In your case, it could look something like

```
<%= collection_select(:cashbook, :account_name, Account.all, :account_name, :account_name) %>
```

Though you should also consider using the `id` column to associate models as per the [Rails Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). If you change your models to use `id`s as the foreign key, you won't need to explicitly specify the foreign key in your `has_many` and `belongs_to` statements, and you can still create a select box that displays account names:

```
<%= collection_select(:cashbook, :account_id, Account.all, :id, :account_name) %>
```